# What does 'examen de grado' mean?

Tags: vocabulario, significado, vocabulario-técnico, lenguaje-académico

This is with regard to university studies. I can only find references saying it means 'university exam', but I was wondering if it meant 'final exam' or similar.

Comment: It is the [Final examination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_examination).

Comment: In Chile, for the law degree, it is called "[examen de grado](https://inoponible.cl/preparacion-examen-de-grado-derecho/)"

Answer (score 5):

Reading about the 'examen de grado' is more a exposition or final project, in Spain is called the 'proyecto final de carrera'

Final examination are the annual exams for the different courses.

The correct translation for that should be 'final year project'

Answer (score 4):

El examen de grado es el proyecto final de carrera. Como puedes ver en este ejemplo de la [Universidad de Navarra](http://www.unav.edu/web/facultad-de-teologia/licenciatura/teologia-historica/examen-de-grado) es cuando expones el proyecto desarrollado ante un jurado. En mi caso para el resumen en inglés puse:

> Bachelor Presentation

Como aún no estás graduado puedes también poner

> Undergraduate Presentation

Para la documentación en vez de *Presentation* pones *Thesis*.

De la [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesis)

> A thesis or dissertation is a document submitted in support of candidature for an academic degree or professional qualification presenting the author's research and findings.

Si quieres ver más información sobre cada país te aconsejo mirar este apartado

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesis#Regional_and_degree-specific_practices_and_terminologies

Porque como puedes ver en el ejemplo de Canada y para las que son de habla inglesa.

> At English-speaking Canadian universities, writings presented in fulfillment of undergraduate coursework requirements are normally called papers, term papers or essays. A long paper presented for completion of a 4-year bachelor degree is sometimes called a major paper.

Answer (score 1):

En Cuba usamos:

Para un el examen de grado que sería el examen correspodiente a un curso de la universidad

> **Examen Final** o **Trabajo de curso**.

Para el último trabajo o examen de la carrera que lleva exposición ante un jurado usamos

> **Tesis** o **Trabajo de Diploma**

Para el examen que evalua todos los conocimientos adquiridos durante la carrera que es para los que no tienen opción de hacer Tesis, se utiliza

> **Prueba Estatal** o **Examen Estatal**